Two kinds of paragraphs
In novels, at least in German typesetting, there are often two kinds of paragraphs:

A paragraph without an empty line, only indicated by a linebreak and and indentation of the next line. These are often used to indicate that a different person is now talking in direct speech.

A paragraph with an empty line and no indentation. These often indicate the end of some logical unit of content.


I wonder what the correct way to have both kinds of paragraph breaks in a tex document is. I only know about paragraph separation by double line breaks, which are by default printed like paragraphs of the first kind described above.


You want to mark up the paragraphs that must be preceded by blank space and have no indentation (personally, I find this really ugly, to be honest).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\PP}{\par\bigskip\everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar{}}}

\begin{document}

\PP % start

This is an unindented paragraph, with some dialog following, let's go on
until this wraps.

«What time is it?» asked Joe.

«It's too late, hurry up,» answered Zoe.

They were preparing coffee in the morning. Now some nonsense in order to
wrap lines, because I don't want to go on with the story.

\PP



Again, this is an unindented paragraph, with no dialog following, let's go on
until this wraps, so we're satisfied that the thing works. Note that the
number of blank lines after (or before) \verb|\PP| is irrelevant.

\end{document}


Explanation: \everypar is usually empty (and in your case you don't need it to contain anything). After \PP it contains {\setbox0\lastbox} that will remove the indentation box; then it resets \everypar to empty.

From egreg's answer using ltpara.dtx code
EDIT: a big mistake, see Frank Mittelbach's comment!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\PP}{
%     \par\bigskip\everypar{{\setbox0\lastbox}\everypar{}}}
    \bigskip
    \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\OmitIndent}%
    % \AddToHookNext{para/end}{\IndentBox}%<-- WRONG! see Frank Mittelbach's comment
    }
\begin{document}

\PP % start

This is an unindented paragraph, with some dialog following, let's go on
until this wraps.

«What time is it?» asked Joe.

«It's too late, hurry up,» answered Zoe.

They were preparing coffee in the morning. Now some nonsense in order to
wrap lines, because I don't want to go on with the story.

\PP

Again, this is an unindented paragraph, with no dialog following, let's go on
until this wraps, so we're satisfied that the thing works. Note that the
number of blank lines after (or before) \verb|\PP| is irrelevant.

\end{document}



Your suggested definition has a bug:  \AddToHookNext{para/end}{\IndentBox} is not necessary because \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{\OmitIndent}is executed only once (since it is "next") so no need to try and undo its setting. More importantly: \IndentBox is the box register so what you do results in adding an "ffl" ligature at the end of the paragraph (because that is what you get if you just typeset the register number) --- you can see that in your screenshot twice.

@Frank Mittelbach I corrected my mistake, I hope I understood and there is no more error

The second variant of formatting seems like a new subsection marked by an empty line. So, I should insert a macro \newpar in these cases. And I should define this macro as:
\def\newpar{\bigskip\noindent}

or in LaTeX:
\def\newpar{\par\bigskip\noindent}

because LaTeX implements \bigskip differently using \vadjust.
If there is a danger that empty line(s) follows the \newpar before next text then the macro should use \ignorepars:
\def\newpar{\bigskip\noindent\ignorepars}
\def\ignorepars{\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA}
\def\ignoreparsA{\ifx\next\par \ignoreparsB \fi}
\long\def\ignoreparsB\fi #1{\fi \ignorepars}

